# Social community management software recommendations

Tags: open-source, web-apps, social-networks

I've got a client with several WordPress hosted websites. Recently, I have been talking to them and they told me their long term idea of their work.

In future, they want to build a community of like minded people that can potentially have thousands of users. Now they have shown me what they have in mind particularly. They want a Facebook like social network with being able to make groups that people can join, posts statuses and have a hashtag tagging and filtering. For example, when someone posts a job opportunity with a #JobOpportunityItaly or #Italy so when you click on #Italy to get a filtered search with job opportunities, announcements and every post with hashtag #Italy.

They have sent me the link to one similar social network and it is [Impact Hub](http://www.impacthub.net/).
It is subscription based network which has all the features which I specified above.
They also want it to be hosted by them and they want to build a social network of like minded people and it can potentially have thousands of people using their network. It would be based on a monthly subscription as well.

They want a long term solution so they don't want anything like a forum or a WordPress plugins like BuddyPress or similar.

What I need are recommendations for social network system solutions either paid or free community editions, free systems, etc.
Also, should I go with a custom solution built completely custom or upon an MVC framework or any other ideas. I'm open for all recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question was asked three years ago, here's a few platforms we've come to appreciate over the years:

1. [Workplace by Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/workplace) - Facebook's entrant to the market
2. [Discourse](https://www.discourse.org/) - for "civilised discussions"
3. [Jive](https://www.jivesoftware.com/) - enterprise player, been around for a while
4. [Vanilla Forums](https://vanillaforums.com/en/software/) - "forums reinvented"
5. [Higher Logic](https://www.higherlogic.com/home) - open source platform
6. [Lithium](https://www.lithium.com/) - growing, acquired Jive-x